# Unable to boot from a Ubuntu Live USB

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb, lenovo

I am using Lenovo Idepad 110 AMD Laptop.

I have Windows 10 installed in my laptop.

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 over Windows.

I did download the ISO file http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ 64 bit from here and made a bootable USB using https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 .

But when I am booting from the pen-drive the UBUNTU logo comes out and after that it says **Uncompression error,system halted** message.

I tried Lenovo Diagonalistics Test and evrything is just fine

I tried shutting down my laptop several times  but the same message comes out every time I boot from the USB.

Please suggest me some ways to fix it.
I really need  a dual boot laptop.

Comment: Did you check the md5sum matched the download (ie. verify the download worked).  To verify the write-to-thumb-drive worked trying to boot it in another machine is easiest  (on second/other machine you don't install, just hit 'try ubuntu'...)

Comment: @guiverc; there are so many versions of ubuntu available;How to check which one will work.Please help

Comment: The bulk of them are different DEskops (flavor of GUI), ie. for KDE use Kubuntu, for MATE use Ubuntu-MATE, for XFCE use Xubuntu, etc. Underneath these flavors are just core Ubuntu (the different apps match the desktop & libs the DE uses). For servers use ubuntu-server (no gui) etc. As for version, 14.04 = 2014 April release which is a LTS (long-term-support) meaning a longer life before its EOL. The latest release was 17.10 (2017-October) but its not a LTS and will be EOL later this year (before the 14.04LTS reaches EOL). You use non-LTS if you want latest & don't mind release-upgrading often

Comment: @guiverc;But why is 14.04 not working and how to fix the error

Comment: as for which DEsktop is best - that's a personal choice, like what flavor ice-cream you like. Only you can decide that, and you may find tastes change. You can always add other DEsktops to your Ubuntu (though it does mess things a little for newcomers; ie. if you want a simple editor, with two desktops you have two choices...)

Comment: Did the download work (ie. md5sum matched what it should have been).  MD5sum is a MD5 checksum which verifies the integrity of the file. Did the write work? (write to usb), ie. it booted in another machine and you could "try ubuntu" successfully meaning the write worked.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM  (md5sums are also used to verify no MiTM (man-in-the-middle) attack, or for security purposes)

Comment: If you want a LTS I would first suggest to download the 16.04 LTS version (14.04 is getting quite old now, especially if you have a new computer...), and use etcher.io to burn it on the usb key. Once you do that, if the error is still there, please tell use when this error occurs (after or before grub ?).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0):

The source of you downloading the .iso file is legit. However, I would suggest you to create a bootable USB using the - Universal USB Installer software.

Download Universal USB Installer from the link: `https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/`

Post making bootable USB, ensure that you have disabled both the Secure boot and PTT Security (in BIOS).

Once done, start the installation process and if you still face an issue, let us know.

Looking forward to your responses.

Regards.

Comment: Okay I wii do it and notify you

Comment: sure. 

one proper bootable usb and disabling of both 'secure boot' and 'ptt security' options is important for a proper installation. 

Awaiting your response.

Comment: I did that but the same message appeared

Comment: Try this link -  https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

It appears to be similar w.r.t the link you have given, yet I want you to redownload the image again. 

There is a possiblilty that while previous download, something broke in between and the image got corrupted.  A fresh download of an image might be able to resolve this issue.

Comment: I downloaded again and made a bootable usb but the same message apperas after booting from it